# need help to fix a pointer array c

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    for (p; p < p + len; p++)
    {
        printf("%c", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char* msg = "hi jyegq meet me at 2 :)";
    printArray(msg, strlen(msg));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to switch some things but I can't understand the problem
I need to fix this code and I think it's with the print of the pointer and I don't know how to print him with no problems

Comment: `p < p + len` is always true for len >= 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printArray(char* p, int len)
{
    ;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", *(p++));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    char* msg = "hi jyegq meet me at 2 :)";
    printArray(msg, strlen(msg));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Use a counter so you wouldn't go somewhere you shouldn't in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will go on indefinitely. Consider what will happen if you substitute the variables with their values. `p > p+len` will go from `0 > 0+20` to `1 > 1+20` and so on. This will always be true. A fix could be to first store the endpoint, like `for (char *end = p+len; p<end; ++p)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
  
void printArray(char* tab, int len)  
{  
    char *p;  
    for (p=tab; p < tab + len; p++)  
    {  
        printf("%c", *p);  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
}  

int main(void)  
{  
    char* msg = "hi jyegq meet me at 2 :)";    
    printArray(msg, strlen(msg));  
    getchar();  
    return 0;  
}
```